# Connect Unity to .NET core API

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, asp.net-core, firebase-realtime-database

Now im working on Unity app which has to communicate in real-time with .net core API . Unity app has to listen for changes on some values on API, and than recive that changes and do some things.
Calling get method in update in unity to see changes is the worst solution.
I tough maybe about firebase in middle, but im stucked at connection to firebase from .net core api.

Any ideas ? Different solutions ?

Could this even work ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: When you say you are stuck, what have you tried so far? Do you have any code you can show us to start from?

Comment: @Michael thanks for feedback Michael. Honestly, spent two days seaching on google , and did not find solution so far so i tried here to see if someone has experience with similar thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to receive changes on the client side, [ASP.NET Core SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/?view=aspnetcore-2.1) is a framework you should look at. It helps to add real-time functionality to apps. [There](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/dotnet-client?view=aspnetcore-2.1) is a documentation on SignalR client, and [there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio) is a tutorial on how to start working with it.

Comment: Thanks for reply Alex. It was only solution i was found so far, but didnt sure could it works.